# List of Starters in dictionaries

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, data-structures

in  the given method called solve which takes as parameter a list of strings called items.

You have to print the list of items for each alphabet. Print in sorted order of alphabets.

Example Input:

noodles, rice, banan, sweets, ramen, souffle, apricot, apple, bread

Output:

a : apple apricot

b : banana bread

n : noodles

r : ramen rice

s : souffle sweets

```
    import collections 
    def solve(items):
          result = {}
          for word in items:
              char = word[0]
              if char in result:
              result[char].append(word)
              else:
             result[char] = [word]
         od = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(result.items()))
         for key, value in od.items():
                    print ("%s : %s"%(key,value))
```

but, im getting it in brakets...! not like a desired output...

Comment: Two hints: (1) You don't do any comparisons in your code, how do you expect it to find out a maximum of anything? (2) What exactly is `d` when your print statements execute?

Comment: d is dictionary!

Comment: `d={}`  vs `for d in stats`

Comment: Your indention is off - you should try to fix it first.  Propose to try `collections.defaultdict` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can try to leverage Python `collections.defaultdict` as this will simply the code logic:

You could convert this easily to the function - maybe *as an exercise*? If you have any questions, please ask.

```
from collections import defaultdict

inputs = "noodles, rice, banan, sweets, ramen, souffle, apricot, apple, bread"

groups = defaultdict(list)

lst = inputs.split(', ')
#print(lst)

for item in lst:
    groups[item[0]].append(item)

for k, val in sorted(groups.items()):
    print(k, ": ", *val)          # *val to expand the list content
```

Output:

```
a :  apricot apple
b :  banan bread
n :  noodles
r :  rice ramen
s :  sweets souffle
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not performing any comparisons to find the maxEnglish or the maxTotalMarks. The reason `print('Max Marks:',d['name'])` is printing the correct result is because `Dwight` is the last entry in the Ordered Dictionary and you are printing the last item's name.

One of the ways you could tackle this question is by keeping variables that keep track of the maximum scores and as you iterate through the dictionary, you can compare against these stored value to determine if the current value
that you are iterating is greater or lesser than all the values that you have seen so far. Something like this:

```
def solve(stats):
    maxEnglishMarks = -1
    maxTotalMarks = -1
    maxEnglishStudentName = maxTotalStudentName = None
    
    for stat in stats:
        totalMarks = sum([i for i in stat.values() if str(i).isnumeric() == True])
        if totalMarks > maxTotalMarks:
            maxTotalStudentName = stat['name']
            maxTotalMarks = totalMarks
        if stat['English'] > maxEnglishMarks:
            maxEnglishStudentName = stat['name']
            maxEnglishMarks = stat['English']
    print('Max English:', maxEnglishStudentName)
    print('Max Marks:', maxTotalStudentName)
            
    
    
stats = [
    {'name': 'Jim', 'English': 92, 'Math': 80, 'Physics': 70},
    {'name': 'Pam', 'French': 72, 'English': 80, 'Biology': 65},
    {'name': 'Dwight', 'Farming': 95, 'English': 85, 'Chemistry': 97}
]

solve(stats)
```

Comment: can u plz check this, for where im going wrong!? 
Example Input:
noodles, rice, banan, sweets, ramen, souffle, apricot, apple, bread
Output:
a : apple apricot
b : banana bread
n : noodles
r : ramen rice
s : souffle sweets

Comment: How does this post answer the PO?

Comment: @DanielHao The original question that was posted has been changed. The current question is a completely different one. If you look at the comments under the post, the initial ones are addressing the previous question.

Comment: @Kainazamin Please do not alter the question (to a new one) once it has been posted. The comments and answers become irrelevant. If you had another question, please create a separate post instead of editing an old post.